# adding a yes no drop down column in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I am really new to using power query and I was hoping somebody could tell me if it's possible to add a column to a connection-only query with a data validation that is simply a yes/no dropdown. Below is the query that is created for the creating a new column and I really don't even know if what I am trying to do is even possible.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "C1 Made Contact?", each "")
```

thanks in advance

Comment: No, it isn't. It wouldn't really make much sense anyway.

Comment: What would be the thing you are trying to do with that ?

Comment: @horseyride i am pulling in data from a SharePoint file onto a shared workbook that will be editable by numerous agents. Basically, I wanted to add a Yes/No column for them to update when they had called the customer

Comment: sounds like perhaps you want to incorporate changes in the data back into the query? Not sure that is possible using sharepoint as the source but see https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/   Otherwise use the output as a new input you can preserve